# Can I inject mocks into a prototype bean with Autowired constructor?

Tags: java, spring, mockito

Is it possible to inject a mock service into a prototype bean using the `@Autowired` constructor? I realize I could switch to setter injection but I would prefer to use the constructor if possible.

```java
@Component
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class Prototype {

    private DependantService dependantService;

    @Autowired
    public Prototype(DependantService dependantService) {
        this.dependantService = dependantService;
    }
}
```

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class TestPrototype {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Mock
    private DependantService dependantService;

    @Test
    public void testPrototype() {
        // How can I inject the mock service?
        ctx.getBean(Prototype.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is an overloaded version of the `getBean` method that accepts arguments. I would downvote my on question if I could.

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class TestPrototype {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Mock
    private DependantService dependantService;

    @Test
    public void testPrototype() {
        Prototype p = ctx.getBean(Prototype.class, dependantService);
        // Test p
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to speed up your unit tests, [and do *true* isolated unit testing,] I suggest taking a look at the `@InjectMocks` mockito annotation. `@SpringBootTest` fires up the Spring container which is pretty cumbersome.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
 @Inject
 private Logger log;


 public methodThatNeedsTesting(){
  log.info("hey this was called");
 }
}
```

```
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ExtendWith({ MockitoExtension.class })
class MyControllerTest {
 @Mock
 private Logger log;

 @InjectMocks
 private MyController myController;
 
 @Test
 void test_methodThatNeedsTesting() throws Exception {
  myController.methodThatNeedsTesting();
  // myController will not throw an NPE above because the log field has been injected with a mock
 }
```